# is_constructible in c++17 for types without user defined constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, c++17

I would like to check at compile time if a type is constructible from the types of the arguments to its constructor. The static assertion below passes in `C++2a` while fails with `C++17` and the reason why is in the code snippet below the static assertion.  Question: how can I reformulate the static assertion for it to work with C++17 ?

```
struct X
{
   int x;
   float y;
};

int main()
{
   static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<X, int, float>);
   
   // Below is valid in both C++17 and 2a
   X x1{10, 1.3f};

   // Below is only valid in C++2a
   X x2(10, 1.3f);
}
```

Comment: "*Question: how can I reformulate the static assertion for it to work with C++17 ?*" That would be a lie. The reason the assert fails is *because* the code fails. The whole point of `is_constructible` is to detect if a type can be initialized with constructor syntax given a set of types. In C++17, an aggregate cannot be initialized with constructor syntax in that way, so it *should* be false. Any other answer would be incorrect.

Comment: Are you asking how to check to see if a type can be initialized by list initialization from some sequence of types?

Comment: @Artyer yes it does, thanks!

Comment: This is aggregate initialization and test case (2) has only existed since C++20 see definition(5) here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization